# Rails devise: how to allow guest user to add a record then confirm the record only after sign up confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to allow guest user to add a record to DB, then confirm the record only after sign up confirmation?

**More details:**

I want to allow guest user to submit a review, then I want to save it in database with a flag that it is unconfirmed, after making the review I want to require user to sign up & then I will send him a confirmation email (normal devise sign-up & confirm flow)

**Is there any default/preferred way to achieve this?**

I have looked everywhere but I can't see this use case for devise/rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some callbacks that you can use with Devise, the one that will interest you is `after confirmation`.

For instance:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :reviews
  # ...

  def after_confirmation
    super
    # associate the pending unassociated review
    reviews << Review.where(guest_user_nickname: nickname)
    # update the status of the review
    reviews.update(confirmed: true)
  end
end
```

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Callbacks

Comment: Thanks Samy, that was very helpful, I wonder if there is some other default way to make a temporary record or I should just use the callback, but anyways this did the trick, thanks